# temporarily 'reset' namespace in #define

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces

I was wondering whether there is a way to 'reset' a namespace. I'm mainly asking this because I would like to specialize some template structs in another namespace using a define.

Here is a simplified example of what I would possibly like to achieve:

```
namespace base {
    template<typename>
    struct my_traits;
}

// specialize base::my_traits for TYPE
// obviously, this does not work
#define MAKE_SPECIALIZED_TRAITS(TYPE)           \
    namespace ::base {                          \
        template<>                              \
        struct my_traits<TYPE> {                \
            typedef TYPE type;                  \
            enum { size = TYPE::size };         \
        };                                      \
    }

namespace spec {
    struct my_struct {
        enum { size = 3 };
    };

    MAKE_SPECIALIZED_TRAITS(my_struct)
}
```

Is such thing possible? If so, how would I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fun technique that might work to use overriding and ADL to generate your traits class.

This is pseudo-code, but it might go something like this:

```
namespace base {
  // a template function you override in your OWN namespace to use this trick:
  template<typename T>
  void my_traits_mapping( T const& ) {};

  // SFINAE enabled internal my_traits.  if you have default traits, put them here:
  template<typename T, typename=void>
  struct my_traits_impl;

  // Detect if my_traits_mapping has been overriden for T, and if so inherit
  // my_traits_impl from its return value:
  template<typename T>
  struct my_traits_impl< T, typename std::enable_if< !std::is_same<
      void, decltype( my_traits_mapping( std::declval<T>() ) )
    >::value >::type >:
    decltype( my_traits_mapping( std::declval<T&>() ) )
  {};

  // you might want to put the above in its own sub-namespace, so as not to clutter
  // up your interface... if it is in details or aux, people will be less tempted to
  // directly mess with it.

  // forward my_traits<T> to the impl type above.
  template<typename T>
  struct my_traits : my_traits_impl<T> {};
}
```

where I use ADL on `T` to call `my_traits_mapping` with an instance of `T`, extract the return type, and inherit `my_traits_impl` from it (so long as it isn't `void`).

Now, instead of specializing `my_traits`, all you do is create a function `my_traits_mapping(X)` that returns a traits class in your own namespace.  When a `my_traits<T>` is evaluated, this function is found, the return value is found, and its type is used to build `my_traits<T>`.

Nothing leaves your `namespace`, but you magically inject your type into the traits system *without* injecting anything into the traits `namespace`.

Get rid of the `namespace` and `template` stuff in your macro.  Instead, create a `my_traits_FOO` type in a `details` namespace, then add `details::my_traits_FOO my_traits_mapping( FOO const& )` to the namespace you invoke the macro in, which should be the same namespace as `FOO` is declared in.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I would never have thought about using ADL that way. I always assumed I needed a `using ...` statement to enable ADL.

Comment: @TodKnapen ADL just needs a type and an argument.  The above is a bit cheeky, in that it uses ADL on a type without an instance of the type, but I couldn't figure out a way to pull off what you asked without a bit of hackery.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of sounding tautological (and not intending to trivialize the problem), if you don't want a name to be defined in a namespace, don't define it in a namespace.

```
namespace spec {
    struct my_struct {
        enum { size = 3 };
    };
}
MAKE_SPECIALIZED_TRAITS(spec::my_struct)
```

Incidentally, I'd leave out the closing semicolon in the macro and put it at the point where the macro is used. That looks more "normal" to me:

```
MAKE_SPECIALIZED_TRAITS(my_struct);
```

Comment: I might have oversimplified my original problem. My original problem was that I have a define which creates some type in the namespace it is invoked in, but should specialize a template class in another namespace for that type. So the problem isn't that I don't want something to be defined in a namespace, the problem is that I need to specialize something in a pre-defined namespace which may or may not be the same as the namespace the define is invoked in.

Answer (score 0):

doesn't this work?

```
   #define MAKE_SPECIALIZED_TRAITS(TYPE)        \
        template<>                              \
        struct ::base::my_traits<TYPE> {        \
            typedef TYPE type;                  \
            enum { size = TYPE::size };         \
        };
```

UPDATE:

I made this work in a test:

namespace base {
  template struct my_traits;
}

```
#define MAKE_SPECIALIZED_TRAITS(TYPE)        \
    namespace base { \
      template<>                              \
      struct my_traits<TYPE> {        \
          typedef TYPE type;                  \
          enum { size = TYPE::size };         \
      }; \
    }

namespace spec {
  struct s {
    enum { size = 10 };
    int o;
  };

}

MAKE_SPECIALIZED_TRAITS(spec::s)
```

Comment: Your link is unreachable for me. Why doesn't it work? What are the error messages?